# Passing ngModel to directive in controllerAs component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-controlleras

From a directive using the controllerAs declaration, I want to pass a scope variable to a nested directive, that is to be used within. I want any changes from "inside" to be reflected on the outside, and vice versa.

Grabbing the variable through an isolated scope is not an option, as the controllerAs directive is already asking for an isolated scope. [See example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YwTd83PwH30hotPAUD2z)

I have come up with this, in the inner directive:

```
link: function($scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
    $scope.ngModel = {};
    $scope.modelValue = ngModel.$modelValue;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return ngModel.$modelValue;
    }, function(newValue) {
        $scope.ngModel = newValue;
    });

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.ngModel;
    }, function(newValue) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
    }, true);
}
```

- as seen in the [following example](http://plnkr.co/edit/llKQrx0bxiFsmMGYE3In), but it seems very hacky. How is this done best?

Comment: In link function 4th argument is controller is it not? So is your controllerAs property assigns you controller to ngModel identifier?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. 4th argument is the ngModel controller, yes.

Comment: "controller is the directive's required controller instance(s) or its own controller (if any). The exact value depends on the directive's require property" and you say that you're using controllerAs so your controller is accessible with ngModel parameter.